# Arduino and PHP web page

Tags: php, arduino

I am trying to get a PHP web page to take temperature readings from the [Arduino Uno](http://arduino.cc/en/Main/ArduinoBoardUno) with an Ethernet shield, through an Apache web server. I am writing the temperature reading to a text file and then taking it from there onto the [PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) webpage, using two PHP files.

However, I cannot get the temperature reading to the text file. I am not sure if the Arduino code is incorrect and is not sending the temperature reading or if the PHP code is incorrect and not taking in the temperature reading. I know the Arduino and the webpage are communicating as I am reading back from the webpage to the serial monitor.

#### Arduino code

```
#include <Ethernet.h>  //Library for Ethernet functions
#include <SPI.h>
#include <Client.h>    //Library for client functions

byte MACaddress[] = {0x90, 0xA2, 0xDA, 0x0D, 0x8B, 0xB3};  //Replace with your Ethernet shield MAC address
byte IPaddress[] = { 192,168,1,102};  //The Arduino device IP address
byte subnet[] = { 255,255,255,0};
byte gateway[] = { 192,168,0,1};
IPAddress server(192,168,1,100);      // IP address of server the Arduino sends data to
EthernetClient client;
bool connected = false;

int sensorInPin = 0;
float temperature = 0;

void setup(void)
{

    Serial.begin(9600);
    Serial.println("Initializing Ethernet.");
    delay(1000);
    Ethernet.begin(MACaddress);

    Serial.println("LM35 Sensor ");
    analogReference(INTERNAL);
}

void printTenths(int value)
{
    // Prints a value of 123 as 12.3
    Serial.print(value / 100);
    Serial.print(".");
    Serial.println(value % 10);
}

void loop(void)
{
    int span = 20;
    int aRead = 0;
    for (int i = 0; i < span; i++)
    {
        aRead = aRead + analogRead(sensorInPin);
    }
    aRead = aRead / 20;
    temperature = ((100 * 1.1 * aRead)/99) * 10;

    if (!connected)
    {
        Serial.println("Not connected");
        if (client.connect(server,80))
        {
            connected = true;
            //int temp = analogRead(A1);
            Serial.print("Temp is ");
            Serial.println(temperature);
            Serial.println();
            Serial.println("Sending to Server: ");

            client.print("GET /arduino.php?t0=\n");
            Serial.print("GET /arduino.php?t0=\n");
            client.print(temperature);
            Serial.print(temperature);
            Serial.println();
            client.println();
            client.println("HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            Serial.println();
            Serial.println("HTTP/1.1\r\n");
            client.println("Host: localhost\r\n");
            Serial.println("Host: localhost\r\n");
            client.println();
            client.println("User-Agent: Arduino\r\n");
            Serial.println("User-Agent: Arduino\r\n");
            client.println("Accept: text/html\r\n");
            Serial.println("Accept: text/html\r\n");
            client.println();
            Serial.println();
            delay(1000);
        }
        else
        {
            Serial.println("Cannot connect to Server");
        }
    }
    else
    {
        delay(1000);
        while (client.connected() && client.available())
        {
            char c = client.read();
            Serial.print(c);
        }
        Serial.println();
        client.stop();
        connected = false;
    }
 }
```

### Arduino.php code

```
<?php
    echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s");
    file_put_contents("C:\Folder\Mechatronics Application\Semester 2\Project               \Hello.txt",$_GET['t0']);
?>
```

#### Index.php code

```
<?php
    echo date("d.m.Y-H:i:s");
    $string1 = file_get_contents("C:\Folder\Mechatronics Application\Semester 2\Project\Hello.txt");
    echo $string1;
?>
```

Comment: sure that this is PHP?

Comment: You would have to do some basic debugging yourself before any of us is able to help you. First try to find out what goes wrong exactly and if you still have questions after that please ask.

Comment: You may also want to read about [PHP's escape sequences](http://php.net/manual/en/regexp.reference.escape.php)

Comment: I think @PeeHaa is right, your filenames are getting clobbered. As [Mike Sherrill 'Catcall'](http://stackoverflow.com/users/562459/mike-sherrill-catcall) suggests, if you put something into your text file with a text editor (forgetting the arduino) it will not show either.

Answer (score 0):

One of the principles of general systems theory is "A complex system designed from scratch never works and cannot be patched up to make it work. You have to start over, beginning with a working simple system."

In your case, this means "Divide and conquer."

Your server/[PHP](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/PHP) subsystem doesn't need to know anything besides the path to a text file. That text file doesn't *have* to have anything to do with your microcontroller. Just create a text file with dummy data in your editor. Put it under version control. Make your server/PHP subsystem work with it. Now that text file is part of your regression tests.

Enhance that a little with a [cron](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Cron) job that runs a shell script or a short PHP, [Ruby](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Ruby_%28programming_language%29), or [Python](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Python_%28programming_language%29) program to write reasonable random data at regular intervals. When that works, your web page should show the data changing over time.

Once *that* works, you can start hammering on the Arduino subsystem, knowing that the server/PHP side is good.

Comment: This is definitely PHP. I tested the PHP files separately, i.e. assigning a string, then using the arduino.php code to put it into the text file and the arduino.index to call it from the text file and write it to the web page. My problem seems to be around the $GET function.

Comment: PeeHaa the "PHP's escape sequences" is the answer. The \n in the arduino code was stopping the transfer of the temp value. I have been stuck on this for a very long time and I have tried a lot of different things, so thank you very much.